# Q: Zoho CRM: Create relationship (lookup) with Lead/Contact email not ID

Tags: crm, zoho

When adding an event via the request URL, do I absolutely need the Contacts/Leads record ID or is there a way I can add the Contact to the event with just their email address?

I'm adding events to CRM and I am able to add the 'Event Owner' which is field type 'lookup' with email. I then try the same with Contact Name (Who Id), but the relationship is not made with the email. I need to use the record ID, but would love to end with email.

Event fields:

```
<Events>
    <section name="Event Information" dv="Event Information">
        <FL req="false" type="Lookup" isreadonly="false" maxlength="120" label="Event Owner" dv="Event Owner" customfield="false"/>
        <FL req="true" type="Text" isreadonly="false" maxlength="255" label="Subject" dv="Subject" customfield="false"/>
        <FL req="true" type="DateTime" isreadonly="false" maxlength="120" label="Start DateTime" dv="Start DateTime" customfield="false"/>
        <FL req="true" type="DateTime" isreadonly="false" maxlength="120" label="End DateTime" dv="End DateTime" customfield="false"/>
        <FL req="false" type="Lookup" isreadonly="false" maxlength="120" label="Who Id" dv="Contact Name" customfield="false"/>
        <FL req="false" type="Text" isreadonly="false" maxlength="100" label="Remind At" dv="Remind At" customfield="false"/>
    </section>
</Events>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can only add the Contact to the event with the ID, so what I did was retrieved the contact ID from the submitted email, then added to event.

```
if(isset($formvars['user_email'])){

    $url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Contacts/searchRecords?authtoken=TOKEN&scope=crmapi&criteria=((Email:". $formvars['user_email'] ."))&selectColumns=CONTACTID";

    $xmlresponse = simplexml_load_file($url);

    $client = (string) $xmlresponse->result->Contacts->row->FL; 

}
```